# Убрать объекты с определенным типом из массива с JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, объекты

Помогите решить задачу

Напишите функцию, цель - убрать все объекты с типом `additional`, а для `basic` очки уменьшить в двое, изменить необходимо исходный массив:

```
const myLesson = [
  {lesson: 1, type: 'basic', points: 2},
  {lesson: 2, type: 'additional', points: 4},
  {lesson: 3, type: 'basic', points: 6},
  {lesson: 4, type: 'additional', points: 3},
  {lesson: 5, type: 'basic', points: 4},
  {lesson: 6, type: 'basic', points: 2},
  {lesson: 7, type: 'additional', points: 2},
  {lesson: 8, type: 'basic', points: 6},
  {lesson: 9, type: 'basic', points: 4},
  {lesson: 10, type: 'basic', points: 6},
  {lesson: 11, type: 'additional', points: 5}, 
  {lesson: 12, type: 'basic', points: 2}, 
  {lesson: 13, type: 'additional', points: 2}, 
  {lesson: 14, type: 'basic', points: 4},
  {lesson: 15, type: 'additional', points: 1},
  {lesson: 16, type: 'additional', points: 7},
];
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @dIm0n, перечитай правила.

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле?

Comment: @dIm0n, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy "Составные вопросы с элементарной задачей без попыток её решить.
Именно в эту категорию попадают вопросы-домашки." -- вопрос попадает в эту категорию, по-моему

Comment: @dIm0n, нет, это атомарный. Есть массив и надо его преобразовать, причём на месте, а не создав новый - всё конкретно и по делу. Нет никаких "создать страницу", "получить с сервера" или "вывести в виде списка" - есть только то, что надо сделать и ничего лишнего.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function go(a) {
  for (var q=0, i=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
    if (a[q].type !== 'additional') {
      a[i++] = a[q]
      if (a[q].type === 'basic') a[q].points /= 2
    }
  }

  a.length = i
}

const myLesson = [
  { lesson:  1,   type: 'basic',        points: 2 },
  { lesson:  2,   type: 'additional',   points: 4 },
  { lesson:  3,   type: 'basic',        points: 6 },
  { lesson:  4,   type: 'additional',   points: 3 },
  { lesson:  5,   type: 'basic',        points: 4 },
  { lesson:  6,   type: 'basic',        points: 2 },
  { lesson:  7,   type: 'additional',   points: 2 },
  { lesson:  8,   type: 'basic',        points: 6 },
  { lesson:  9,   type: 'basic',        points: 4 },
  { lesson: 10,   type: 'basic',        points: 6 },
  { lesson: 11,   type: 'additional',   points: 5 }, 
  { lesson: 12,   type: 'basic',        points: 2 }, 
  { lesson: 13,   type: 'additional',   points: 2 }, 
  { lesson: 14,   type: 'basic',        points: 4 },
  { lesson: 15,   type: 'additional',   points: 1 },
  { lesson: 16,   type: 'additional',   points: 7 },
]; 

go(myLesson)
console.log(myLesson)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Оптимизировано ;-). Вот бы еще точки с запятой добавить и вместо `var` =>`let`

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов как можно это реализовать:

```js
let myLesson = [
    {lesson: 1, type: "basic", points: 2},
    {lesson: 2, type: "additional", points: 4},
    {lesson: 3, type: "basic", points: 6},
    {lesson: 4, type: "additional", points: 3},
    {lesson: 5, type: "basic", points: 4},
    {lesson: 6, type: "basic", points: 2},
    {lesson: 7, type: "additional", points: 2},
    {lesson: 8, type: "basic", points: 6},
    {lesson: 9, type: "basic", points: 4},
    {lesson: 10, type: "basic", points: 6},
    {lesson: 11, type: "additional", points: 5},
    {lesson: 12, type: "basic", points: 2},
    {lesson: 13, type: "additional", points: 2},
    {lesson: 14, type: "basic", points: 4},
    {lesson: 15, type: "additional", points: 1},
    {lesson: 16, type: "additional", points: 7},
]

myLesson.forEach((item, index) => {
    const type = item.type
    if (type === "additional") {
        delete myLesson[index]
    } else if (type === "basic") {
        myLesson[index] = {
            ...myLesson[index],
            points: myLesson[index].points / 2
        }
    }
})

myLesson = myLesson.filter(Boolean)

console.log(myLesson)
```

Comment: `filter` - это не изменение на месте